# Prefix each header with X retaining the original structure

Tags: for-loop, awk, header, delimiter, gsub

I'm having some difficulty to edit a tab delimited matrix.
I can't show you the original file, because it has 445 fields and 318 lines.
The original file is like this:

```
OTUId            198  341A  341B  341C  201  200  205
OTU103080889      0   600    0    200    0    0    2 
OTU104847416      0   450    0    1870   0    0    0
....
```

The first problem was when I loaded in R, I have that problem about having numbers as header, so, in order to not lose all the analysis done, I changed the header from this example above using this:

```
awk 'NR==1{ for(i=1;i<=445;i++) gsub ("^", "X", $i); }1' my_otu_table.txt >> teste.txt"
```

It worked for adding the X in front of each field, but I lost the tab delimited original format.

I've been looking for this final complement to my awk sentence above, but I'm having difficulty to fix it.

Could you help me, please?
Thank you 
Sorry, I don't know how to format a table in this post

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: For information you lose the tab formatting because updating any field invalidates `$0`, which is rebuilt with the output field separator (`OFS`) when referenced. One way to fix your portable awk command would be `awk 'NR == 1 { gsub(/[^[:space:]]+/, "X&") } 1' input_file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's easier to do this with GNU sed:

```
$ sed '1s/\</X/g' file
XOTUId            X198  X341A  X341B  X341C  X201  X200  X205
OTU103080889      0   600    0    200    0    0    2
OTU104847416      0   450    0    1870   0    0    0
```

Comment: The OP asked to prefix every column names but, just to mention, GNU sed would also accepts `sed '1s/\</X/2g' file` to add the prefix starting from the 2nd column.